# Can You Help Identify This Dryer Part Left Over

Tags: dryer

I have a maytag bravo dryer model #medx700xl0.  This piece (Thick plastic card) was was left over after I removed the drum, cleaned up the inside and replaced the heating element.  Dryer is working and heating which was the goal, but this piece was on the floor. None of the "take apart" diagrams seem to show this piece.  Anybody know what it might be?  I'd like to put it back on.

[image]

Comment: find a place where you removed two screws with that spacing ... it looks like a cover to keep wiring away from moving parts .... it could also be a deflector to direct air towards the motor

Comment: examine the part closely ... there may be a part number stamped on it

Comment: Often used above electrical components just in case of water drips. One reason why you should take pictures before taking things apart - especially when you are new at it.

Comment: Do you remember taking this out of the dryer or was it already lying on the floor before you started working on it?

Comment: It's like working on a car - If you have parts left over, you've improved the OEM engineering. ;)

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  I'm kicking myself for not taking some pictures as I took it apart.  Any chance it would be around the heating element?  I'll take the lint filter and that cover off and look again.  Thanks again.  Any other thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you again for the replies. Solar Mike &  Jsotola - your comments led me to the fuses and sure enough.  Two holes on the front panel were there and the piece fits in a manner that covers the fuses from possible dripping as clothes are placed in the drum.  Thanks alot!  Two minutes to locate and re-install it.